# Plot 2d point on 3D plane drawn in 2d

Tags: math, 3d, 2d, equation, perspective

I am attempting to draw a point from a 2d plane on a 3d plane that is drawn in 2d.  I'm not sure how to adjust the y position based on the angle of the perspective.  As you can see in the image linked below (Stack Overflow won't let me include the image because I just signed up), if the point is at the center point of the rectangle, it would need to be shifted up slightly when viewed from an angle to account for distance from the viewer.  Can anyone provide an equation to help?

[image: Example Image]

Comment: If you only ever need to draw a point at the exact center of the rectangle, draw an X that connects the corners of the rect, and draw the point at the intersection of the two lines that make up the X.

Comment: I need to draw points anywhere on the shape.  The center point was just to simplify the example.

Comment: Do you understand scaling and translation, and the idea of coordinate transformation?

Comment: to some degree, yes.  But I'm not drawing this in 3d.  I know there should be an equation to draw the point on the Y axis to appear 3d, but I just don't have a strong enough background in math to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Say the point in the rectangle is given by (x,y), and the coordinates we're looking for in the second image are (x', y').

w  = y + y<sub>0</sub>
y' = k atan(w/h)
r  = sqrt(h<sup>2</sup> + w<sup>2</sup>)
x' = k atan(x/r)

where k is a scaling factor for the whole image, h is "altitude of the viewpoint above the plane" and y<sub>0</sub> is, roughly, distance to the object.

Comment: You might need `atan2()` to put the coordinates in the right quadrant.

Comment: @Lorehead: I always use atan2 myself, but I wanted to keep this answer as simple as I could.

Comment: Thank you.  This makes sense, but unfortunately I don't have most of those variables to work from.  I'm working off a mockup so all I have are the outer dimensions.  I could probably use your solution with a fair amount of trial and error for k, h and y0

Comment: @crashton: It shouldn't take all that much trial. Try k=1, h = y0 = 100 to start with.